# Configure TextMate to run clang instead of gcc for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, textmate, llvm-clang

I'm running latest TextMate 1.5 (on OSX Lion) and have the latest XCode 4.3 installed. 
I'm sort of taking the low road when learning Objective-C by bypassing XCode for start and doing plain samples and exercises using TextMate and command line. When hitting Cmd-R in TextMate the (console) something builds and runs typed Objective-C console program. However, it doesn't compile things that it should (from my POV) compile, since compiling them from command line with clang works fine.  When I switch to building from command line I see that those same things fail when I use gcc instead of clang.

My question is - how do I convince TextMate to use clang instead of gcc when I hit Cmd-R for Objective-C (.m) source files?

(I waded through bundle settings but to no avail, googled it, etc. So it must be either something dead simple that I'm missing or nobody ever wanted to go that way. I'm assuming the first.)

P.S. I converted from Windows some weeks ago so don't assume that I'm an expert Mac user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to do this:

1. Bundles > Bundle Editor > Show Bundle Editor
2. Expand 'C'
3. Select 'Run' command
4. Replace 'GCC' with 'CLANG' in the `when "objc"` case (it is the `g` variable)

Comment: efharisto Alladinian, that does it.

Comment: @maksa _Parakalw_. Now that we have the new objc literals Textmate is very handy for quickly evaluating code snippets. I guess that the developers will eventually make clang the default compiler in a future version.